# How to create dynamic URLs on WordPress?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, page-template

I have a site where users can download freeware software.

I want to create a dynamic download page. How to prevent the `https://example.com/software-name/download/` URL from returning 404. `/download/` is a software download page.

I want the page to be dynamic, accessible via:

`http://example.com/name-software1/download/`

`http://example.com/name-software2/download/`

`http://example.com/name-software3/download/`

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible via [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/), be sure to check the comments in the page as well.

Comment: You asked this question previously at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/369421/how-to-make-a-dynamic-download-page, do not do that, especially as a low reputation user there's a high risk the automated system will flag you as a spam bot. If your question doesn't attract enough attention to get a response, edit it to improve it, don't ask it again

Comment: @Tom Thanks for letting me know, I'm still learning to use this site.